# Laravel 9 - laravel new command has error: Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Process\Process::getIterator(int $flags = 0)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to try to install Laravel 9 for the first time...
so, I update my PHP to the latest one (version 8.1.2) and composer to latest one also (version 2.2.6)...

and when i call `laravel new my-project` command, it shows error

```
Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Process\Process::getIterator(int $flags = 0) should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\LAPTOP-SYAMSOUL\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php on line 620

Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\Users\LAPTOP-SYAMSOUL\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\HelperSet.php on line 94
```

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sounds like you should run `composer global update` to update the packages that you've installed globally.

Answer (score 21):

Composer needs to be updated

```
composer self-update
composer global update
```

Comment: this is also working code

Comment: I did both but did not work out for me in the beginning. I think there are other configurations for Mac. You MUST add `sudo` to be the `root` user to have proper upgrade.

Comment: Hi Sharif, thank you for your feedback, it's tested on Windows from my side no idea about Mac

Comment: This should be the correct answer, without the "composer self-update" command first, the solution didn´t work. Tks!