# Image Intervention Can Not Be Installed On Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, intervention

I'm using Laravel v9.4 with PHP v8.2 and I wanted to install Image Intervention package on my project, so I ran:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

But I get this error:

**PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traver
sable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/
symfony/console/Helper/HelperSet.php on line 112**

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71141918/laravel-9-laravel-new-command-has-error-deprecated-return-type-of-symfony-co

Comment: @DhairyaLakhera I can't even run any composer command! It shows me the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the composer itself. Update your composer using this command: `composer global update`

Comment: Even running composer command shows me the same error: **PHP DEPRECATED!**

Comment: Maybe redownload composer again. https://getcomposer.org/download/